# Agregar SSL en todos los subdominios

Tags: php, ssl, https, cpanel

Actualmente estoy creando mis subominios con la API de cPanel, todo funciona correctamente. Estoy implementado el protocolo SSL, y en el dominio funciona bien, mi pregunta es, como agrego SSL a los subdominios al momento de crear con la API de cPanel en PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un SSL WildCard resuelves ese inconveniente.

Los certificados SSL Wildcard protegen la dirección URL de tu sitio web, así como también un número ilimitado de sus subdominios. Por ejemplo, un certificado Wildcard individual puede proteger www.buenejemplo.com, blog.buenejemplo.com y store.buenejemplo.com.

Estos certificados protegen el nombre común y todos los subdominios con el nivel que desees especificar cuando envíes tu solicitud.

Ejemplos
Si solicitas tu certificado para *.buenejemplo.com, podrás proteger:

- coolexample.com
- www.buenejemplo.com
- photos.buenejemplo.com
- blog.buenejemplo.com

Si solicitas tu certificado para *.www.buenejemplo.com, podrás proteger:

- www.buenejemplo.com
- mail.www.buenejemplo.com
- photos.www.buenejemplo.com
- blog.www.buenejemplo.com

Los certificados Wildcard protegen los sitios web de manera similar que los certificados SSL tradicionales, y las solicitudes se procesan utilizando los mismos métodos de validación. Sin embargo, algunos servidores web podrían requerir una dirección IP exclusiva para cada subdominio en el certificado Wildcard.

Fuente: [GoDaddy.](https://es.godaddy.com/help/que-es-un-certificado-ssl-wildcard-567)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones:

1.-Comprar un certificado valido para todos los subdominios.

2.-Instalar un certificado de Let's Encrypt que son gratuitos acá lo podrás configurar a tu manera y agregarle la opción de que sea valido para todos los dominios, te dejo el link para que puedas verificar que tipo de servidor y versión tienes.
**LINk**
https://certbot.eff.org

Si necesitas ayuda para esto me puedes consultar sin problemas